# Datatable column input value

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am using datatable in Springboot+Java project.
I used datatable as below.

I want to put {data:uid} value to first column's input(checkbox) value.
Or input's id or classname as well.

What should I do???

```
$('#UserSetting_dataTable').DataTable( {
         ajax : {
             "type" : "POST",
             "url" : "test.do",
             "dataType" : "JSON",
         },
         columns : [
             {data : null, defaultContent:""},
             {data : "uid"},
             {data : "email"},
             {data : "name"},
             {data : "corp"},
             {data : "department"},
             {data : "i_group"},
         ],
         'columnDefs': [{
             'targets': 0,
             'searchable': false,
             'orderable': false,
             'className': 'dt-body-center',
             'render': function (data, type, val, meta){
                 return '<input type="checkbox" name="id" class="checked" value="">';
                 },
         }],
         'order': [[1, 'desc']]
     });
```

PLZ HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
columns : [
          {
              data : "uid",
              defaultContent:"",
              'targets': 0,
              'searchable': false,
              'orderable': false,
              'className': 'dt-body-center',
              "render": function (data, type, row) {
                  return '<input type="checkbox" data-status="'+data+'" value="'+data+'" class="checked">';
              }
            },
          {data : "uid",}
```

Used render option to insert value of the data in checkbox input...!